# DocumentRoot Path in browser?

Tags: apache-2.2, unix

I'm using Apache v2.2.26 on Mavericks and I am unable to understand why `http://localhost/~username/Sites/` returns a `404` error, when, in fact the directory, `Sites`, exists, whereas `http://localhost/~username/arbitrary-script.php` displays the correct website, or, script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `~username/Sites` is configured as the root directory for the `~username` web site, so only everything below is accessible, without the `Sites` part. If `http://localhost/~username/Sites/` would be accessible, this would mean that e.g. `http://localhost/~username/Documents/` would also be available as it is on the same level and you would end up showing your whole home folder.

Comment: It somewhat makes sense, but I'm still new to the command line, so I'm still confused as to why `Sites` wasn't showing in the full path.  I was thinking of it the same way you navigate file paths in terminal.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of the same way, but in this case it starts at the `Sites` directory and everything below is hidden. Quite frankly, this is such a very fundamental issue that it has no real place on [SF], which is targeted at professional administrators ([help], [valid topics](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)). Sites like [SU], [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be a better fit, but please check their help centers before posting.

Comment: When you say, `below`, do you mean the directories that come before it in the path?  Also, forgive me, I'm new to the stack community.  Too many options mixed with an over analytical personality trait, returns many mistakes, and newbie questions.

Comment: Yes, however my wording was flawed - I should have said *above* as it is customary to consider sub directories as *below*. Can't edit it anymore, though.